# Update WordPress Posts Inside Loop

Tags: wordpress, loops

I have some processing inside my WordPress loop, and I want to "cache" the results so that the next time the post is displayed I can use the pre-processed info. The obvious place to store the results is as post metadata.

I have therefore incorporated a number of Update_post_meta calls into my code, along the following lines:

```
update_post_meta($imagePostID, "imageMeta", $imageMeta);
```

In this the value of $imagePostID is just the numeric Post ID, which I have already used to retrieve other metadata, so that's OK. I have also confirmed that the code is getting called at the right point.

However, the values are not getting saved, and it looks like for some reason the updates are just being ignored.

Does anyone understand why this is, and if there's any way to get the behaviour I want?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Have you checked directly in the database that the metadata is not saved at all? Can you show us the loop / PHP code?

Comment: yes please post your code surrounding this post meta so we can get a better idea of whats going on.. i just tested this concept myself and everything worked in the database side.

Comment: It's working now. The problem was somewhere around how I was checking for the cached values. Apologies for the mis-call. Thanks for all the help.